# Android Development - Should I use an XML based layout, or just code in java?

Tags: java, android, layout

An opinion question for somebody just starting out in Android development. All the tutorials I'm finding seem to assume you're using an XML based layout. I have quite a bit of Object Oriented Programming experience, and wonder if I should still use XML or just skip it and program my views directly in Java?

Your thoughts? Good sites / articles / books I should read?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not a super experienced Android programmer, but I definitely recommend learning both. XML based layouts really facilitate your tasks later on.

I was in the exact same position as you are right now. I decided to skip XML (hey, I knew Java and OO!) and regretted it.

Check out The New Boston Channel on Youtube for learning about XML and how to use XML layouts with your code:

http://www.youtube.com/user/thenewboston?feature=watch

The tutorials are great and informative.

Good luck!

Comment: +1. Using plain code to create layouts and views is a great overkill. But you still need to use Java to create views if you want to do something uncommon (e.g. your custom View) which can't be done by styling common views.

Comment: This is some great input, thanks guys, keep the responses coming

Answer (score 2):

Best thing about the XML layouts is that you can whip them up in a GUI builder and then put them in your app with 1 line.
If you want clever interactive things, you need to learn the programatic side of it (which is trivial if you know Java and OO).

Learn the Android concepts - activities, views. Your existing Java knowledge will help greatly!

Answer (score 1):

Again it depends on your requirement. Suppose you want to render the UI components dynamically then it's good approach is to use Java. When you know what UI components you need to use for screens and they are static better go to xml approach.

When you are designing and handling the dynamic components then its easy to implement and handle in Java.

Suppose you have a screen already already defined in your application and the components inside that are static then go for xml

Comment: I will be making simple games with it, so I don't know if I will have much chance to use the XML side of things, though I understand I can mix and match XML and java based views?

Answer (score 1):

Use XML-based layouts so that you can easily adapt your application for [different screens](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html), OS versions, locales, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Android UI is fundamentally based on Views and ViewGroup.

Straight from http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/index.html.

> The most common way to define your layout and express the view hierarchy is with an XML layout file. XML offers a human-readable structure for the layout, much like HTML

Ofcourse if you need yours views to change dynamically or you need view customization you need Java code.

In one word XML layouts are "advisable". And remember the saying "Writing code is fun. But do not reinvent the wheel”

http://developer.android.com and google IO videos are best to learn android app development. Additionally you can also check [Newboston](http://thenewboston.org/) and [Marakana](http://marakana.com/) tutorials  .

Answer (score 0):

If your activity layouts contains only static views, then go for the xml file but if you need to add your views randomly/dynamically depending on some conditions then go for the java code.

Xml file provides better layout alignments with lesser overhead.

Comment: yeah, I keep reading that XML is more optimized, funny how that is

Answer (score 0):

If you are familiar most with coding part of UI then its best approach otherwise xml is  simply thing which not provide dynamically changes with the ui. When you set the ui with  coding then you can easily manipulate it according to dynamic change. Do you want ask which  would prefer or any else?? Please elaborate your question much more.

Best,
V.k

Answer (score 0):

You starts with XML first. Before you make decision on which is the best, you should experience both of them first. In my opinion, XML is better in a lots of way. From time to time, I whip in a few custom layout that is context sensitive of some sort. Other than that, XML-based is really comfy way to do. You will need to write so much code for a simple LinearLayout with multiple views inside while maintaining proper screen position :-/

But end of the day, you should be choosing anything you are comfortable with. So, try both :)

Comment: sounds like I should learn both, thanks for all the input everyone!